# Why won't my NPC capsule wander?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first time attempting to make anything resembling an "AI". Basically, all I want is for a capsule to occasionally choose a location in the world, raycast to see if there are any obstacles in the way, and if there are none then move to that location.

My first attempt was like below except without the WaitForSeconds yield and isWandering debounce. This version had the capsule move jaggedly and very slowly towards a point. My theory was that this might be caused by the bot trying to "wander" multiple times simultaneously, thus the debounce.

I have also tried with higher / lower 'npcSpeed's, to no avail. Here is my code as it stands:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class npcController : MonoBehaviour {

    CharacterController control;
    Vector3 movement;
    bool isWandering = false;

    public float npcSpeed = 3f;


    void Start(){
        control = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }

    void Update(){

        if (Random.Range (1f, 10f) > 8f && isWandering == false) {
            isWandering = true;
            Wander ();
        }

    }

    public bool IsWanted() {
        return true;
    }

    IEnumerator Wander(){

        int randX = Random.Range (1, 10);
        int randZ = Random.Range (1, 10);
        float moveDistance = Mathf.Sqrt (randX ^ 2 + randZ ^ 2);
        float moveTime = moveDistance / npcSpeed;

        Vector3 check = new Vector3 (randX, 0, randZ);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (!Physics.Raycast (transform.position, check, moveDistance)) {

            transform.LookAt (check);

            control.SimpleMove (Vector3.forward * moveTime);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (moveTime);

            isWandering = false;

        }

    }

}
```

The GameObject I am trying to move is a capsule with a CharacterController and the npcController script.

*Edit: For confirmation, the jagged movement was not caused by any frame drops. The game was running at above 170fps the entire time*

Comment: if you move the Wander() outside of your if-statement, and have it call only `if (isWandering == true)`, does this fix it?

Comment: not the solution to your issue, but i fear the `^` operator does not do what you think it does. its not the power, its the bitwise xor, use `Mathf.Pow(float base, float exponent)` instead (or in case of a simple square, just n * n). see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Pow.html

Comment: @ryeMoss dont quite understand what you mean

Comment: @yes  Ah ok, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a coroutine by simply by it's name. You have to use `StartCoroutine(Wander());` and that should start the enumeration for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your debounce, Wander() only gets called for one frame so your player only moves for one frame. it doesn't get called again until your timer runs which is probably why you are getting jittery movement. You need quite a bit of rework here however, because if you change it so that you call Wander() every frame while `isWandering==true`, the yield statements will 'stack' and you'll probably get some unwanted results. You can get away without using a coroutine for a timer here and can just move your character while `isWandering == true`.

```
int randX, randZ;
float moveDistance, moveTime;
Vector3 check;
void Update()
{
    if (Random.Range(1f, 10f) > 8f && isWandering == false)
    {
        randX = Random.Range (1, 10); // movement parameters are set once here
        randZ = Random.Range (1, 10);
        moveDistance = Mathf.Sqrt (randX ^ 2 + randZ ^ 2);
        moveTime = moveDistance / npcSpeed;
        check = new Vector3 (randX, 0, randZ);
        isWandering = true;
    }
    if (isWandering) // Wander every frame while true
        Wander();
}

float timer;
void Wander()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer < moveTime) // move until timer exceeds movetime
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (!Physics.Raycast (transform.position, check, moveDistance)) 
        {
           transform.LookAt (check);
           control.SimpleMove (Vector3.forward * moveTime); 
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        timer = 0; //reset timer and debounce
        isWandering = false;
    }
}
```